# how to integrate extjs5 model, store,controller and view

Tags: netbeans, extjs5

In Extjs5 how to integrate app model, store, controller with view using netbeans8.0 ...

Ext.define('Coplinsurance.view.aftermarket.AfterMarketComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'aftermarket',
    title: 'Clint Name:',
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'form',
        // flex: 2,
        //labelAlign: 'top',
        padding: 5

```
},
layout: {
    type: 'vbox'
},
items: [
    {
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            padding: 5
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        title: 'After Market',
        items: [
            {
                allowBlank: false,
                minLength: 3,
                maxLength: 25,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                fieldLabel: 'Supplier',
                name: 'supplier',
                width: 250
            },
            {
                allowBlank: true,
                minLength: 3,
                maxLength: 25,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                fieldLabel: 'Invoice Price',
                name: 'invoiceprice',
                width: 250
            },
            {
                allowBlank: false,
                minLength: 3,
                maxLength: 25,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                fieldLabel: 'Commission',
                name: 'commission',
                width: 250
            },
            {
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                fieldLabel: 'excluding GST:',
                boxLabel: 'Premium not financed'

            }
        ]
    }, {
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            padding: 5
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        title: 'Other Insurance / Warranty',
        items: [
            {
                allowBlank: false,
                minLength: 3,
                maxLength: 25,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                fieldLabel: 'Supplier',
                name: 'supplier',
                width: 250
            },
            {
                allowBlank: true,
                minLength: 3,
                maxLength: 25,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                fieldLabel: 'Invoice Price',
                name: 'invoiceprice',
                width: 250
            },
            {
                allowBlank: false,
                minLength: 3,
                maxLength: 25,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                fieldLabel: 'Commission',
                name: 'commission',
                width: 250
            },
            {
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                fieldLabel: 'excluding GST:',
                boxLabel: 'Premium not financed'

            }
        ]

    }, {
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            padding: 5
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        title: 'Other Insurance ',
        items: [
            {
                allowBlank: false,
                minLength: 3,
                maxLength: 25,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                fieldLabel: 'Supplier',
                name: 'supplier',
                width: 250
            },
            {
                allowBlank: true,
                minLength: 3,
                maxLength: 25,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                fieldLabel: 'Invoice Price',
                name: 'invoiceprice',
                width: 250
            },
            {
                allowBlank: false,
                minLength: 3,
                maxLength: 25,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                fieldLabel: 'Commission',
                name: 'commission',
                width: 250
            },
            {
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                fieldLabel: 'excluding GST:',
                boxLabel: 'Premium not financed'

            }
        ]

    },
    {
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            padding: 5,
            align: 'center'
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        items: [
            {
                allowBlank: true,
                minLength: 3,
                maxLength: 25,
                labelWidth: 120,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                fieldLabel: 'Total Invoice Price',
                name: 'totalinvoiceprice',
                width: 400
            },
            {
                allowBlank: false,
                minLength: 3,
                maxLength: 25,
                labelWidth: 120,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                fieldLabel: 'Total Commission',
                name: 'totalcommission',
                width: 400
            }

        ]

    }
]
```

});

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: this is a view .i dont no how to create model, store and integration with each other with controller.